# How can i add a navigation drawer to my activity , if i already have a tabbed view in my activity

Tags: android, xml, android-tabs, navigation-drawer

i have a tabbed activity and after i add with right click->new -> activity -> navigation drawer.
how can I insert a navigation drawer activity if i already have a tabbed activity structure?

Comment: This is an awesome [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-a-navigation-drawer-in-an-android-app--cms-30263) for adding drawers to an activity, take a look at it and if you need further assistance, do tell.

Comment: I know how to add it but I do not know how I can add it to an existing project

Answer (score 0):

In the navigation drawer activtiy change your layout like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="in.net.spectrum.citytour.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    //
    //
    // Tab layout to show tabs
    //
    //
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/tbl_pages"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<!-- <include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    //
    //
    //ViewPager to show tab's fragments
    //
    //

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_pages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your Activity Java code inside onCreate() add these lines :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           .
           .
           .
           .

    ViewPager vp_pages= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp_pages);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter=new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vp_pages.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tbl_pages= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl_pages);
    tbl_pages.setupWithViewPager(vp_pages);

    }
```

Now outside onCreate() method create the fragment adapter :

```
class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new YourFragment1();
            case 1:
                return new YourFragment2();
            case 2:
                return new YourFragment3();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position){
            //
            //Your tab titles
            //
            case 0:return "Profile";
            case 1:return "Search";
            case 2: return "Contacts";
            default:return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not understand, I already have a structure as I can add a navigation drawer without messing up anything?